# How to use all cores in my cluster Spark for a process?

Tags: apache-spark

How to use all cores on my cluster Spark for a process?

I can´t configure all cores for run my process in cluster Spark.

Comment: In Spark, you have executors and cores. If you know how many cores are there in your cluster then you need to configure the spark.executor.instances and spark.executor.cores properly. Please refer https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Comment: What type of cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was mentioned in comments - setting number of cores in executors I suggest also take into consideration partitioning topic. Otherwise you might have all cores used, but doing nothing.